# c# build an oject to be serialized on the fly

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have to return a serialized JSON object from an AHSX handler
I have no corresponding class, and I'd like to avoid to create this, because they could be several. 
So I'd like to create it like the following code:

```
string serialResponse = jsonSerializer.Serialize(
        new
        {
            query = "Li",
            suggestions = new[] { "Liberia", "Libyan Arab Jamahiriya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania" },
            data = new[] { "LR", "LY", "LI", "LT" }
        }
    );
```

but my object has a different structure and I don't know exactly how to build it using the above pattern:

It's a list of objects, representing products inside a cart, like the following:

```
{
name = "Shoes",
price=123.45,
quantity=2,
color="black",
size="9"
},{
name = "Shorts",
price=13.45,
quantity=1,
color="pink",
size="L"
}... etc
```

How can I build this list using the new {...} notation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you can create some dynamic objects and then serialise into a json string.
Something like this:

```
dynamic o1 = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
o1.hello = "Hello";
dynamic o2 = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
o2.number = 42;
o2.AnotherNum = 43;
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new []{o1,o2});
```

Comment: so it's not possible to use the compact notation new{...} as in the example code? It seems quicker to write and read than using dynamic

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, you can only declare an anonymous object and not an anonymous array of anonymous object. @Giox